# Recyclerview inside nestedscrollview - slow scroll android 6?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a nestedscrollview in my app. the problem is the scroll is slow.

The problem only occurs in android 6.

I have this in my class:

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/pro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


        <ImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewP"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/p2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pro"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


        <TextView
            android:text="Sells"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:layout_marginRight="66dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="66dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/idFollowers"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView4" />




        </RelativeLayout>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_below="@+id/p2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

any ideas how to get a smooth scrolling? why it is slow in my android 6?

Answer (score 1):

why are you nesting a RecyclerView in a NestedScrollView, the RecyclerView already handles its own scroll, its possible they are both struggling to gain focus.
Add these to the RecyclerView

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Add this to the NestedScrollView

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

also as already pointed out, the swipeRefreshLay could also be the culprit